# How can I skip ajax in capybara 1.4.1 using selenium webdriver (2.27.2)

Tags: capybara, selenium-webdriver

I am getting timeout error because of image loading using Ajax and it is taking lot of time so I want to skip/ignore ajax request. (I am using capybara 1.4.1 and selenium 2.27.2)

webkit skips loading image but selenium not why? suggest me if any solution.

Comment: There's no such version as 1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use webkit-driver which avoid image load